# Extracting information with grep

Tags: bash, du

On my Ubuntu 14.10 server I need to check the size of user folders that are located at

`/home/docks/*userid*`

I am something of a bash newbie but I have gotten this far

`du -csh /home/docks/userid | grep total` will return, say,

`16K  total`

Now I don't really care about total so I want to trim that further and just get the 16K.  I imagine that there is a relatively simple way to do this in a shell script.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to tell me how.

Comment: du -csh /home/docks/userid | grep total | cut -d "t" -f 1 <- du gives it out with tabs so its t a delim

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer - a slight correction: That should be `cut -d \t -f 1` since the white space character there is a tab, not a space.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't run it first but than I saw that du uses tabs

Comment: @DroidOS why do you use `-c` and `-s`? `du -sh` produces the `total` directly, just one line. So just use `du -sh /path` and then cut or awk

Comment: @fedorqui - Iike I said I am something of a bash newbie. `du -sh` produces something like `25M    .`. I am not sure that the white space there is - neither tab nor space by the looks of it.  I tried `du -sh | cut -d "M" -f 1` which works with the slightly risky assumption that it is always going to be M (not K or G or something).

Comment: But I understood from your question that you want the number and the unit. So `25M`, not `25`. Is it right?

Comment: @fedorqui Right.  I used M since it is not clear to me what that white space to be cut is - neither tab nor space worked.

Comment: @DroidOS you can either say `cut -d\  -f2` (note, two spaces!) or `cut -d" "  -f2`. But safer in `awk`, as Avinash recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a problem with counting the size of user folders when language version is different than English and 'total' word in output might appear in a different language.

A little "hack" preventing from such a situation (taking into consideration that summary is always printed as last line in `du` output):

```
du -csh /home/docks/userid | tail -n 1 | cut -f1
```

Or you can just use:

```
du -sh /home/docks/userid | cut -f1
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.  As I often think to myself - what would I ever do without Stackoverflow.  @pstanisz I am accepting your answer since it is the simplest.  Nevertheless it is nice to be given so many options.

Answer (score 1):

A simple awk will do this job you don't need to go for grep.

```
du -csh /home/docks/userid | awk '/total/{print $1}'
```

OR

```
du -csh /home/docks/userid | awk '$2 ~ /^total$/{print $1}'
```

**OR**

```
du -csh /home/docks/userid | grep -oP '\S+(?=\s+total\b)'
```

`\S+` will match one or more non-space characters. `(?=\s+total\b)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by the string `total` preceded by one or more space character.

Comment: Of course this will also match if the name of any user directory contains "total", so `awk 'END{print $1}'` might be more appropriate.

Comment: `du -csh /home/docks/userid | awk '$2 == "total"/{print $1}'`